# jQuery select box Show/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I show/hide div with jquery select box. this worked but when back/click to empty option value(`Choose Color`) jquery not hide last div.

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".red").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".green").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".blue").show();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box" >You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
```

How do fix this problem ?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/9yR4f/

Comment: That's because you have no code for hiding it...

Comment: @Shahar: add css update in Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd reduce that whole thing to:

```
$("select").change(function () {
$('div.box').hide();
    $('div.box.'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9yR4f/1/)**

Comment: +1 for **thinking** about the whole process instead of filling a hole like the other answers...

Comment: @j08691:+1 Great But in my code if i add `selected` in default option, jQuery show div for option selected. how to work your code for default option selected like this : `<option value="red" selected>Red</option>`

Comment: @j08691:please see my complete code:`http://jsfiddle.net/Tdafh/6/` 1 - i validate select box using jquery selectbox plugin. when you submit form without value(ie :remove red from select box)  u see red error if u click outside selectbox red error switch to green error. i think `change(); conflicted with line 59. 2 - if remove selected from option select2 not work and not styled option.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the code for the default! Add an attribute to the first option:

```
<option value="default">Choose Color</option>
```

Now for the Javascript, add a clause to when it is selected to make it all disappear:

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == "default"){
    $(".box").hide();
}
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yR4f/4/

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do this...

Try this:

Give a value to the "Choose color" option. For example: `value="none"`.

```
<option value="none">Choose Color</option>
```

Add this in your script:

```
if($(this).attr("value")=="none"){
    $(".box").hide();
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yR4f/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a value to your "Choose color" item (ie : none) and add an entry to your if/then block

```
<script src=jquery.js></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".red").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".green").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".blue").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="none")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();

                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
    <div>
    <select>
        <option value="none">Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box" >You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```